# polynomials of degree 3 over finite field

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields

Is there conditions that the polynomials of degree 3, ($f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$) have roots in finite field $F_q$? What is the conditions that the polynomial $2x^3-dx^2+1$ have root on $F_p$? Please help or hints me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is rather strongly Galois theoretic, but after all, finite fields belong also to Galois theory ...

Let us recall briefly the general setting for the determination of the Galois group $G=Gal(N/K)$ of the splitting field $N$ of a given irreducible polynomial $f\in K[X]$, where $K$ is a field of characteristic $\neq 2$. Thinking of $G$ as a permutation group of the roots $x_j$ of $f$, an important invariant is the *discriminant* $D$ of $f$, defined as $D=\Delta^2$, where $\Delta$ is the product of the factors $(x_i - x_j)$ over all the pairs $(i, j)$ s.t. $i<j$.  The origin of the discriminant lies in the explicit expressions for the roots of a quadric, or of a cubic (see Cardano's formulas e.g. in Wikipedia). Obviously $D\in K$, and a permutation $s$ of the roots is even (resp. odd) if $s(\Delta)=\Delta$ (resp. $-\Delta$) (the condition $char(K)\neq 2$ intervenes here), so $K(\Delta)$ is the fixed field of the subgroup  of $G$ consisting of even permutations.

If we specialize  to a cubic $f$, $G$ is a subgroup of $S_3$, hence the Galois group of a separable *irreducible* cubic is either $A_3$ or $S_3$, and it is $A_3$ iff $\Delta \in K$, i.e. $D$ is a square in $K$. In the general case  $f=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, a boring computation using the symmetric functions of the roots gives $D=b^2c^2+18abcd-27a^2d^2 -4ac^3 -4b^3d$. Note that in characteristic $\neq3$, a simple linear change of variables will reduce to the case of a trinomial $f=X^3+bX+c$, in which case the discriminant takes the classical form $D=-4b^3-27c^2$.

Back to your question: a cubic $f$ is irreducible over $K$ iff it has no root in $K$; if moreover $K$ is a finite field, any extension of $K$ of finite degree is Galois, so the splitting field $N$ of an irreducible cubic has degree $3$ over $K$. All in all, the answer is: a separable cubic has a root in a finite field $K$ iff its discriminant $D$ is *not* a square in $K$. Finally the special cubic that you mention over $\mathbf F_p$ boils down to a *non* quadratic residue condition if $p$ is odd. The case $p=2$ is obvious  ./.

Comment: @ nguyen quang do: You write that: a cubic has a root in a finite field $K$ iff its discriminant D is not a square in $K$. Why? Please explain more.

Comment: At the beginning of the last §, we saw that f has no root in a finite field K iff f is irreducible, in which case its splitting field over K has degree 3, i.e. its Galois group is $C_3=A_3$. But in the preceding §, we saw that the case $A_3$ corresponds to D= a square in K.   OK ?

Comment: The above answer concludes with the assertion that "a separable cubic has a root in a finite field $K$ iff its discriminant $D$ is not a square in $K$".  This is not true.  If the cubic has three roots in $K$ then its discriminant is a square in $K$ -- for instance, $x^3-x$ has discriminant $4$.  I gave references for reducibility criteria for cubics and quartics in my answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144974/irreducibililty-tests-for-cubic-and-quartic-polynomials-over-finite-fields.

Comment: It has been a long time, so I may have forgotten some details, but it seems to me that in my answer, the cubic *f* is always supposed to be irreducible. Isn't it ?